# Qt mobile android build error with android ABI level 15, but works with higher ABIs

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

Error during build only with android ABI level 15, but ok with level 24, in Qt creator (happens both in x86 and ARM android), building for ABI 15 in android studio works.

Qt creator 4.0.3

```
Position 40:36-165 : String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation').

:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/a/android/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), `layoutDirection` was added in API level 17, so you'll need to build for at least API level 17 in order to specify that your app is going to handle configuration changes due to layout direction changes by itself.